# Spring.Core.TypeMismatchException: Cannot convert property of type [...] to required type [...]

Tags: c#, nhibernate, spring.net

my problem is that I cannot do any test anymore after I made a tfs update on the project I'm working on. 
Before the update it worked but now I'm getting a `Spring.Core.TypeMismatchException` everytime I run the `ContextRegistry.GetContext()` method in my testclass' `Init()` method.

The only changes on MyProjectDao were changes within its methods and the attributes were added. And a service has been added to the SpringContext.xml.

This is the exception I get:

> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException:
>   System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException:  Error creating
>   context 'spring.root': PropertyAccessExceptionsException (1 errors);
>   nested PropertyAccessExceptions are:
>
> [Spring.Core.TypeMismatchException:   Cannot convert property value of
>   type [CompositionAopProxy_f81c875c2f994f88bb773f5743050b67] to
>   required type [MyProject.Dao.MyProjectDao] for property
>   'MyProjectDao'.,          Inner Exception:
>   Spring.Core.TypeMismatchException:            Cannot convert property value
>   of type [CompositionAopProxy_f81c875c2f994f88bb773f5743050b67] to
>   required type [MyProject.Dao.MyProjectDao] for property
>   'MyProjectDao'.
>                  at Spring.Core.TypeConversion.TypeConversionUtils.ConvertValueIfNecessary(Type
>   requiredType, Object newValue, String propertyName) in
>   f:\bamboo-home\xml-data\build-dir\SPRNET-RELEASE-JOB1\src\Spring\Spring.Core\Core\TypeConversion\TypeConversionUtils.cs:MyProject
>   211.] --->    Spring.Objects.Factory.ObjectCreationException: Error creating object with name 'MyProjectService' defined in 'file
>   [C:\Projects\MyProject\MyProject.NET\test\MyProject.Service.Test\bin\Debug\SpringContext.xml]
>   line 147' :           Error setting property values:
>   PropertyAccessExceptionsException (1 errors); nested
>   PropertyAccessExceptions are: 
>              [Spring.Core.TypeMismatchException: Cannot convert property value of type [CompositionAopProxy_f81c875c2f994f88bb773f5743050b67] to
>   required type [MyProject.Dao.MyProjectDao] for property
>   'MyProjectDao'.,      Inner Exception: Spring.Core.TypeMismatchException:
>         Cannot convert property value of type
>   [CompositionAopProxy_f81c875c2f994f88bb773f5743050b67] to required
>   type [MyProject.Dao.MyProjectDao] for property 'MyProjectDao'.         at
>   Spring.Core.TypeConversion.TypeConversionUtils.ConvertValueIfNecessary(Type
>   requiredType, Object newValue, String propertyName) in
>   f:\bamboo-home\xml-data\build-dir\SPRNET-RELEASE-JOB1\src\Spring\Spring.Core\Core\TypeConversion\TypeConversionUtils.cs:MyProject
>   211.] --->        Spring.Objects.PropertyAccessExceptionsException: PropertyAccessExceptionsException (1 errors); nested
>   PropertyAccessExceptions are:          [Spring.Core.TypeMismatchException:
>   Cannot convert property value of type
>   [CompositionAopProxy_f81c875c2f994f88bb773f5743050b67] to required
>   type [MyProject.Dao.MyProjectDao] for property 'MyProjectDao'., 
>         Inner Exception: Spring.Core.TypeMismatchException:             Cannot
>   convert property value of type
>   [CompositionAopProxy_f81c875c2f994f88bb773f5743050b67] to required
>   type [MyProject.Dao.MyProjectDao] for property 'MyProjectDao'.
>                  at Spring.Core.TypeConversion.TypeConversionUtils.ConvertValueIfNecessary(Type
>   requiredType, Object newValue, String propertyName) in
>   f:\bamboo-home\xml-data\build-dir\SPRNET-RELEASE-JOB1\src\Spring\Spring.Core\Core\TypeConversion\TypeConversionUtils.cs:MyProject
>   211.].

MyProjectDao class looks like this:

```
namespace MyProject.Dao
{
    [DataAccessObject]
    [Transaction(TransactionPropagation.Mandatory)]
    public class MyProjectDao : IMyProjectDao
    {
        public ISessionFactory SessionFactory { private get; set; }

        // ... Methods ... 
    }
}
```

The IMyProjectDao interface:

```
namespace MyProject.Dao
{
    public interface IMyProjectDao
    {
        // ... Methods ... 
    }
}
```

this is a part of my SpringContext.xml

```
<!-- ######################## -->
<!--            DAO           -->
<!-- ######################## -->

<object id="MyProjectDao" type="MyProject.Dao.MyProjectDao, MyProject">
    <property name="SessionFactory" ref="SessionFactory" />
</object>

<!-- ######################## -->
<!--          Service         -->
<!-- ######################## -->

<object id="MyProjectService" type="MyProject.Service.MyProjectService, MyProject">
    <property name="MyProjectDao"       ref="MyProjectDao" />
    <property name="PersistenceService" ref="PersistenceService" />
    <property name="DeletedObjectCache" ref="DeletedObjectCache" />
</object>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using the interface 'IMyProjectDao' in the MyProjectService for the MyProjectDao property or are you using the class 'MyProjectDao'.

If you use the class change it to the interface.

Change your property in the MyProjectService class from:

```
public MyProjectDao MyProjectDao { get; set; }
```

To

```
public IMyProjectDao MyProjectDao { get; set; }
```

Comment: This is very likely to be the issue. I guess the problem started when @Lyndon added added the `[Transaction ..]` attribute; that causes spring to create a composition based proxy for the interface(s) of the `MyProjectDao` type, instead of simply using the type `MyProjectDao` itself.